# Can I sell buildings? If so, how?

Tags: super-mario-run

I accidentally bought way too many Red Toad houses as I thought they would stack in the same location, on top of each other(they don't).  Can I sell my unused buildings? If so, how?

Comment: *Super Mario Run: Real Estate Broker Edition!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, no, you can't. However, it shouldn't take long to earn the coins needed to buy things again!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't but you can put them away, to do this go to the main screen tap Build then Put away than tap what you want to put away.